# Flutter d-pad navigation

Tags: flutter

I am writing software for the CHAINWAY C61 device and I focus on using the software only from the keyboard. The first time I start the application, I have no problem using the d-pad.

```
GridView.count(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
             MenuItemWidget(
              'Wydaj rezerwację',
              Icons.article,
              () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ReservationsPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
```

It is enough that the focus will be set on the textField and the directional keys do not work anymore.

```
TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    showCursor: false,
                    controller: _textEditingController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Indeks',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.error,
                      ),
                    ),
```

I noticed that the directional keys start working after waking up the application again, but unfortunately it is impossible to work like that. I am asking for some hint to solve this problem ....

Answer (score 0):

i think you need some container wrapper to get focus navigation using this package

https://pub.dev/packages/dpad_container